# 'GETPIVOTDATA' causes a formula parse error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use the [GETPIVOTDATA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6167538?hl=en) function to recreate a column from the pivot table in a new sheet.

I used the formula:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("SUM of Ut", 'Pivot Table 1')
```

I also tried

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("SUM of Ut", 'Pivot Table 1'!A1)
```

The column I want to recreate is called 'SUM av Ut' and everything can be found here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jdbBvpgR9NnuXYW5waOqAf7utC2valQOFscmgocM3kk/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Add to the question the actual formula that you wrote.

Comment: Thanks Ruben, done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spreadsheet use comma as decimal separator and semicolon as argument separator.

To solve the problem, on your formula replace the comma by a semicolon